Org-babel remote inline images with TRAMP not exporting in org export
I am trying to find a way to get the images generated in my remote server exported to a HTML locally. Orgmode of a local analysis works as expected, but if I have tramp enabled with:
#+PROPERTY: header-args R :dir "/ssh:name@server:/home/name/folder" :session R-ea-server :exports both :cache yes

Then something like this won't work when I print out the report with org-export html:
#+header: :width 1500 :height 1000 :res 150 :type cairo
#+BEGIN_SRC R :exports both :session R-ea-server  :dir "/ssh:name@server:/home/name/folder" :results output graphics file :file graphs/missing.png
# deselect all genetic PCs from 4 to 10 for both twins
dt %>%
  select(-c(genetic_pc_4_T1:genetic_pc_10_T1, genetic_pc_4_T2:genetic_pc_10_T2)) %>%
  vis_miss(.)
#+end_src



#+RESULTS[a25483d148e45469ed82d0fbfc16235de2deee8b]:
[[file:/ssh:name@server:/home/name/folder/graphs/missing.png]]



The image above is "cached" by TRAMP locally and is displayed normally in Emacs.

Is there a way to make the TRAMP locally saved image show up in the printed report?


Do you know where the images are stored locally? I'm not sure cache header creates and stores images locally. I suspect you'll need to add an extra code block to copy the remote images to local directory for org-export html to work correctly. But I'm not sure.

I will have to look into TRAMP code, as I can't find the info in the manual. The images are cached by TRAMP (I am sure because they are shown when I open emacs without connecting to the server), but I can't find where.
